# Sandboxed web part failing with "No available sandboxed code execution server could be found"

Tags: web-part, deployment, error, sandbox-solution, service

I'm deploying a web part as a component of a sandboxed solution from Visual Studio 2010 to Windows 7 SharePoint Foundation Server 2010 on my development box, and I receive the following error when viewing the web part on the deployed web part page:

```
Web Part Error: No available sandboxed code execution server could be found.

[SPUserCodeExecutionPipelineFailedException: No available sandboxed code execution server could be found.]
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionManager.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPSite site, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartRemoteExecutionHelper.<>c__DisplayClassa.b__9() 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartRemoteExecutionHelper.ExecuteRequestInSandBox(HttpContext context, SPWeb web, SPWebPartManager manager, SPUserCodeWebPart userCodeWebPart)

[SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.222.1:32846]

 Server stack trace: 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(IPAddress[] addresses, Int32 port) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket(AddressFamily family) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket() 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketCache.GetSocket(String machinePortAndSid, Boolean openNew) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.SendRequestWithRetry(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg) 

 Exception rethrown at [0]: 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPUserCodeExecutionHostProxy.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String affinityBucketName, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionManager.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPSite site, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)
```

I've heard this can be related to the 'SharePoint 2010 User Code Host' service being stopped, and sure enough it isn't running. However, when I start the service it immediately stops itself, with no warning or error (the Event log only shows the "started successfully" message).

This in turn (I've heard) may be related to the 'SharePoint Foundation Search V4' service being stopped, but this isn't the case.

Has anyone else come across this issue and managed to resolve it?

---

Edit:

I've found the following several times in the SharePoint logs:

```
Performance Counter OS (pdh) call failed with error code PDH_INVALID_HANDLE.     
 - Unhandled exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Unknown error (0xc0000bbc)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Win32.SPPdh.CheckReturnValue(PDH_STATUS status, Boolean throwOnError)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPPerformanceCounter.NextValue(Int32 retry, Int32 retryInterval)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodePerformanceCounterHelper..ctor(String processName, Int32 processInstanceId) thrown while reading perf counters for process "SPUCWorkerProcess".
```

This can apparently be caused by the 'SharePoint 2010 User Code Host' service running as a user that isn't in the required local user groups WSS_ADMIN_WPG and WSS_WPG. However, my service is using the 'Network Service' user, which is in both groups.

[James Pritz](http://problog.jamespritz.com/refactor/post/2011/06/11/No-available-sandboxed-code-execution-server-could-be-found.aspx) has an interesting article on the matter, but his resolution(s) didn't work for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It has become increasingly obvious that reinstalling SharePoint is going to be necessary.

The symptoms seem to point to a permissions issue with the user accounts used to run the services, which are notoriously difficult to configure correctly outside of SharePoint's own installation process.

Comment: Reinstall? Perhaps you should first try to run SharePoint configuration wizard before going for a reinstall?

Comment: @JanisVeinbergs: I haven't got round to reinstalling yet, but I have run the configuration wizard on several occasions since. The service still has the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

check if the 'Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service' service is started
*SharePoint 2010 Central Administration -> System Settings -> Manage Services on Server*

Comment: I don't appear to have that option under System Settings, and neither does my colleague on his development box...

Comment: Its right under the "Server" headding.

Comment: try this url: <central admin url>/_admin/Server.aspx

Comment: @Heiko: Under that heading I have "Manage servers in this farm", but that's it. Is this a difference with Foundation perhaps?

Comment: @Anand: Ah! That worked, thanks. And yes, the service is started there.

Comment: For others reading this: "Manage servers in this farm" is the link to click, followed by the server's name you want to look at (you may have to log on as the local administrator as I had to).

Comment: well try restarting the service and see if you can find something in the logs

Comment: @Anand: I've just this moment added some log entries to my question. :)

Comment: @Anand: Interestingly, the 'Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service' appears to represent the 'SharePoint 2010 User Code Host' service (restarting the service in Central Aemin causes the other to restart). I've no idea why it's misreporting the service's state in Central Admin, though.

Comment: Thank You! Stop/Start service from there(from CA) helped.

Answer (score 1):

This was the fix for me

Original link: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/0efa29a6-9bb1-4c2f-a4ef-113bb2601aa5/

regedit:

In HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PerfProc\Performance

If "Disable Performance Counters" is 1, set it to 0 !

Then start "SharePoint 2010 User Code host" in  Services.

Comment: That appears to be the same as the last recommendation in the article I linked to in my question (by James Pritz).

Comment: The reg setting set to Zero fixes the issue but it seems after a few days it gets reset? How can I stop this from occuring?

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Add User for service "SharePoint 2010 User Code Host" to "Performance Monitor Users" group.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and I just closed and reopened my PowerShell window to make it work.
Hope this can help in some cases.